# Free software development tools to track software development?

Tags: windows

I've been working for a new company for the last 7months, and I'm the only SW Dev on site. My work seems to be stacking up just now, and my note pad is taking a battering with new features, bugs, and future development.

When I was in uni we used a few SW iteration processes (agile, scrum etc etc) and we use to have some good tools to track what we were doing.

What tools do you guys use to track these kind of things? and could you point me in the direction of a good free app! Most I've found are web based, but would ideally like a native Windows app.

Cheers!
Rocky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your reply guys. After endless searching I found one of the old programs I use to use: GenttProject http://www.ganttproject.biz/

its free, and is a native Windows application. Works nicely for what I need!

Answer (score 1):

If you need something simple [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) often works good. It lacks more powerful project management features, but for simple tracking of todo-items I think it works well.

Comment: thanks, looks like a hefty install for a simple tracker, will have a go after lunch though and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called OnTime which is free for a single user. May be exactly what you are looking for.

http://www.axosoft.com/ontime

Comment: thanks for this, do you have experience with it? I've downloaded it and got a free key, although it requires a MS SQL db to be running for it to work, I use mySQL for my projects, and installing SQL for tracking might be a bit over kill :S

Comment: I have had a play with it before but I work for a company that already has software in place for tracking projects etc. Yeah I forgot it uses SQL as I use SQL all the time. It should work ok with SQL express which is a free download